# Iron:router error in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, meteor, iron-router

We are developing a Meteor app and we have the following error when we test it in Internet Explorer:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('Home', {
    data: function () { return Items.findOne({_id: this.params._id}) }
  });
});
```

This is the code we have in router.js for Home:

```
Router.route('/',{
  name: 'home',
  layoutTemplate: 'homeLayout',
  title: 'Log in',
  onBeforeAction: function(){
    this.redirect('/sign-in');
    this.next();
  }

})
```

It's random, sometimes the app works and sometimes crashes.
We have reviewed the code and we don't know how to solve it.
Versions we are using:
iron:router@1.0.13
MeteorJs: 1.3.5

We have these error in JS Console:

```
 SCRIPT5022: Router.route requires a path that is a string or regular
 expression. SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'length'::
 object is null or undefined –
```

Anybody has the same problem or any solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show the error as well?

Comment: We have reviewed the console (js console) and running app in production mode and there's nothing in consoles. No errors.

This is what we get when we run the app, instead the login page:

iron:router Organize your Meteor application.
Router.route('/', function () {
this.render('Home', {
data: function () { return Items.findOne({_id: this.params._id}) }
});
});

Comment: @Styx today we have these error in JS Console:    SCRIPT5022: Router.route requires a path that is a string or regular expression.
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'length':: object is null or undefined

Comment: Could you edit your question and add this info there?